# Change the origin of Graphics2D coords

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have a simple elevator simulator. The painting class of that simulator, paints a wall on the left side and a wall on the right - both are Line2D Objects. In the center is a rectangle that represents the cabin.

My Member Variables are:

```
private PaintableElevator paintableObject;
private Line2D wallLeftSide = new Line2D.Double();
private Line2D wallRightSide = new Line2D.Double();
private Rectangle2D elevator = new Rectangle2D.Double();
```

paintableObject gives the information where to paint as proportions. For example, if it says that the cabin has a height of 0.1, than its height on the panel is: `this.getHeight * 0.1`

I also have a component Listener that just reacts on rezize Events as follows:

```
@Override
public void componentResized (ComponentEvent e)
{
wallLeftSide.setLine(new Point2D.Double(0, changeYCoordsOrigin(getHeight() * paintableObject.getTotalHeight())), new Point2D.Double(0, getWidth()));

wallRightSide.setLine(new Point2D.Double(getWidth(), changeYCoordsOrigin(getHeight() * paintableObject.getTotalHeight())), new Point2D.Double(getWidth(), getHeight()));

elevator.setRect(0, changeYCoordsOrigin(getHeight() * paintableObject.getHeightInShaft()), getWidth(), paintableObject.getCabinHeight() * getHeight() *-1);
}
```

My Problem is that Graphics 2D sets the origin of their coords to the top left hand side. I would like it to have on the button left side. thats why i use my method `changeYCoordOrigin()`

```
public double changeYCoordsOrigin (double coord)
{
   return getHeight() - coord;
}
```

My hope was that I could convert my coords by calculating them minus the current height. That worked. But when I want to set a negative height for the rectangle, my component dont show anything.

But this is very important, because I want to drive my little cabin by the following code:

```
@Override
public void setHeigth (double height)
{
elevator.setRect(0, getHeight() * height, getWidth(), paintableObject.getCabinHeight());
repaint();
}
```

When just dont use `changeYCoordOrigin` and use a positive height, my elevator drives down, when i want to drive up. Because of that it is important to change the origin of the coordinates, or simulate that.

My paint Method just paints that objects:

```
@Override
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
   if (g instanceof Graphics2D)
   {
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2.draw(wallLeftSide);
       g2.draw(wallRightSide);
       g2.setBackground(Color.gray);
       g2.draw(elevator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `g2.translate()`? Also, Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`.

Comment: As the lift will most likely be always in a state of movement, I would suggest creating a lift class with a draw() method for the lift objects. Maintain a set of values (x,y coordiantes) or lift level for movement of the lift will be way easier.